# Select range of data, from first to last appeareance

Tags: mysql

From a table like this

```
----------------------------------
| User | TimeStamp         | Kind|
----------------------------------
| bob  |2015-01-19 03:14:16| err |
| bob  |2015-01-20 02:07:18|  ok | <-- from here |
| bob  |2015-01-21 12:07:18| err |               | 
| bob  |2015-01-22 12:08:26|  ok |               |
| bob  |2015-01-22 13:40:04| err | <-- to here   |
| bob  |2015-01-23 20:07:00|  ok |
| tom  |2015-01-19 03:14:16| err |
| tom  |2015-01-20 02:07:18|  ok | <-- from here|
| tom  |2015-01-22 13:40:04| err | <-- to here  |
| tom  |2015-01-23 20:07:00|  ok |
```

How can I get from the *first* row were Kind=*ok* to the *last* with Kind=*err*

expected result:

```
----------------------------------
| User | TimeStamp         | Kind|
----------------------------------
| bob  |2015-01-20 02:07:18|  ok |
| bob  |2015-01-21 12:07:18| err |
| bob  |2015-01-22 12:08:26|  ok |
| bob  |2015-01-22 13:40:04| err |
| tom  |2015-01-20 02:07:18|  ok | 
| tom  |2015-01-22 13:40:04| err |
```

There is no unique id in the table but timestamps are ordered

**EDIT**: There can be multiple users

Comment: @Strawberry you are right, there are also other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT User, TimeStamp, Kind
FROM mytable
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(TimeStamp)
                         FROM mytable
                         WHERE Kind = 'ok')
                AND
                        (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp)
                         FROM mytable
                         WHERE Kind = 'err')
```

If you want to apply the above query to data where more than one `User` values are involved, then you have to use correlation in the subqueries, so as to get the `MIN` and `MAX` *per user*:

```
SELECT User, TimeStamp, Kind
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(t2.TimeStamp)
                         FROM mytable AS t2
                         WHERE t1.User = t2.User AND t2.Kind = 'ok')
                AND
                        (SELECT MAX(t3.TimeStamp)
                         FROM mytable AS t3
                         WHERE t1.User = t3.User AND t3.Kind = 'err')
```

Alternatively you can use `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.User, t1.TimeStamp, t1.Kind
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT User, 
          MIN(CASE WHEN Kind = 'ok' THEN TimeStamp END) AS ok_time,
          MAX(CASE WHEN Kind = 'err' THEN TimeStamp END) AS err_time
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY User
) AS t2 ON t1.User = t2.User 
WHERE t1.TimeStamp BETWEEN t2.ok_time AND t2.err_time
```

Comment: @HernánEche Amend your question accordingly.

Comment: @HernánEche *don't have users into account* what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean that you select MIN and MAX from an absolute timestamp but not relative to user id

Comment: @HernánEche Can you also check the alternative and tell me how it compares performance-wise with the first solution?

Comment: @HernánEche I fixed the bug, can you please check?

Comment: It runs ok, I can't test which is faster, both seems similar for the data size I have, if later I can distinguish I'll back to comment